# Link image to new tab

Tags: 8, media

I have a problem trying to link image teaser to open in a new tab when clicked. How do i go about that? I know in html is target="_blank" attribute.

Comment: You'll need to provide more context to know where (e.g. module, theme, etc). to have someone answer this.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is with `mytheme_preprocess_field` where `mytheme` is the name of your theme, inside of `mytheme.theme` file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_field().
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
      if ($variables['field_name'] == 'field_mylink') {
        foreach ($variables['items'] as $key => $item) {
          $variables['items'][$key]['content']['#options']['attributes']['target'] = '_blank';
        }
      }
}
```

This would add `target="_blank"` to each value entered for the link field. But you don't mention if the field is a link field or image field though.

Comment: My page has other images but I want to target this one field that has unlimited images